# center location on scanners sweep

Tags: modding, map-editor, starcraft

I want to center location on a place where someone uses their scanners sweep. I know this is possible with the defilers ability dark swarm but i wonder if it is possible with scanner sweep from ComSat Station. There is a unit that is called scanner sweep so maybe it is possible. I tried it with many triggers but none of them seem to work.

Does anybody have an idea how a trigger that would move the location to the scan would look like?

It doesn't matter which player scans I just want the location to move with each scan.

Answer (score 1):

Years ago, when I was making maps for Starcraft 1, I looked into trying to do this.  However, I recall being unable to use triggers to explicitly center locations on Comsat scans back then, even with custom map editors.

Instead, I had to place pairs of invisible units for computer and neutral players along the map that shared vision with the player.  Then whenever the player used a scan over them (which would reveal them to the player and the player's allies with shared vision), the invisible computer units would move toward the invisible nuetral units to attack them.  I had placed 1x1 locations around the computer units, and used triggers that detected when the specific computer units exited their location.

Even though I could only use this method for important locations in the map, this was the best way I could come up for detecting where a player used comsat scans.  There may be other implicit ways to detect when the player uses comsat scans.

Comment: thanks thats a pretty cleaver answer. Alas it wont come in handy as i cant have tons of invisible units around on this map. Ill still mark it as best answer if no better answer pops up